# C++ pointer arithmetic weirdness

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

I found my bug (after a few hours) and isolated it in the following program. The problem is with the way in which the pst2 variable's value is calculated when using pointers to a struct. When using pointers to char, all works fine. Why is this?
 (Using gcc/g++ version: (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5)
 (For those who are wondering: I'm accessing a file-buffer containing data-groupings at regular offsets.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testpa.h"

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
//---------------------------
struct st_one
{
    int i;
    char c;
};
//---------------------------
struct st_two
{
    long l;
    int i;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

//===========================
int main()
{
    int n=1024, np1=sizeof(st_one); //, np2=sizeof(st_two);
    st_one *pst1, *pst1a;
    st_two *pst2, *pst2a;
    char *pc1, *pc2, *pc1a, *pc2a, *pb;

    pb = new char[n];

    pst1 = (st_one*)(pb);
    pst2 = (st_two*)(pst1 + np1); //using pst1
    pc1 = (char*)(pb);
    pc2 = (char*)(pc1 + np1); //using pc1

    pst1a = (st_one*)(pb);
    pst2a = (st_two*)(pb + np1); //using pb
    pc1a = (char*)(pb);
    pc2a = (char*)(pb + np1); //using pb

    std::cout << "\npb = " << (long)pb;
    std::cout << "\n-----";
    std::cout << "\npst1 = " << (long)pst1 << "\tpst2 = " << (long)pst2;
    std::cout << "\npc1  = " << (long)pc1 << "\tpc2  = " << (long)pc2;
    std::cout << "\n-----";
    std::cout << "\npst1a = " << (long)pst1a << "\tpst2a = " << (long)pst2a;
    std::cout << "\npc1a  = " << (long)pc1a << "\tpc2a  = " << (long)pc2a;
    std::cout << "\n-----\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
pb = 19546128

pst1 = 19546128         pst2 = 19546153  <--- WRONG!
pc1  = 19546128         pc2  = 19546133

pst1a = 19546128        pst2a = 19546133
pc1a  = 19546128        pc2a  = 19546133
```

Comment: I don't see how that's wrong. What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: That's doing it the hard way. What's wrong with `pst1[offset].c`? Let the compiler do the work, it is going to do the pointer arithmetic anyway and is less prone to error than you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks fine to me. The line:

```
 (pst1 + np1)
```

adds `np1` instances of `st_one` to what `pst1` points at, which means that `pst1`s value is incremented by `np1 * sizeof (st_one)` bytes, which is 25 (sizeof = 5), which corresponds to the values you've outputted. Instead of the above, I think you wanted:

```
 (pst1 + 1)
```

The `pc1` value works because that is a `char` pointer, so the line:

```
(pc1 + np1)
```

adds `np1 * sizeof (char)` bytes to `pc1`, which is 5 bytes.

**Incrementing a pointer makes the pointer point to the next element in memory, not the next byte.**

Comment: I was always under the impression that the values inside the brackets gets calculated first before any outside operation is done. In this case I would have thought that the integer-values of pst1 and np1 would be added before being cast as a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't add `sizeof(x)`, because that is done automatically. When you increment a pointer, like ++p, the address is incremented by the size of the object, so that it points to the next one.

Adding 1 to a pointer is the same as ++p. Adding `sizeof(x)` scales the increment twice.

Your calculations work fine for char, because sizeof(char) is 1.

Answer (score 2):

C++ automatically multiplies the integer you're adding by the size of the element the pointer points to. It assumes you want to advance the pointer by whole elements, not bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic in C and C++ is done times the `sizeof` the pointed to type of the pointer. That is, `int *abc = /* ... */; int *def = abc + 1` results in `def` having a result an `int` ahead of `abc`, not a `char`.

As for your casting of the pointers into `long`s, that's implementation defined behavior, so you might get strange results on different machines from doing that.

(For that matter, so is your casting between pointer types. C++ says that's implementation defined too)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got everything wrong. For example, for get pst2 from pst1, you have to increment it by one, as pointer `pst1` is of type `st_one *`, so you have to write like this:

`pst2 = (st_two*)(pst1 + 1);`

.. but you have:

`pst2 = (st_two*)(pst1 + np1);`

... where np1 is a `sizeof` of `st_one`, so it will skip as many `st_one` structures as that structure has bytes...

Read some docs on pointer arithmetic, like [this one](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html).